# Chai Testing Framework Not Giving Message for Passing Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Here is my code:

```
const chai = require('chai')

describe('add',function(){

   chai.should()
   const result = 6

   result.should.be.a('number')
   result.should.equal(6)

})
```

When I run node test I get the following:

```
> mocha



  0 passing (5ms)
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.0.2",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai":"*",
    "mocha":"*"
  }
}
```

Comment: And what if you put an actual spec (`it('...', function() { ... })`) in there?

Comment: But isn't the whole point of Chai to replace the it function.

Comment: I think chai is just an assertion library, you still need the test runner; that's why you have mocha too.

Answer (score 0):

The way to tell Mocha you have a test is to put your test as a callback to the `it` function that Mocha makes available. `describe` groups tests but does not define any test. So if you have a `describe` without `it`, then you have no test.

Chai has no impact on how Mocha operates. Mocha does not care that Chai is there and that you are using it. You can use Mocha with any assertion library that raises an exception or rejects a promise (and return the promise from your test) when an assertion fails. Chai is one such assertion library. And you could use Chai with another test runner than Mocha.